# What is wrong in this NodeJs multer file upload code?

Tags: node.js, multer

I am trying to learn Node's multer library, which is useful for uploading files though API calls,
I have a basic express application setup listening to port 4300,
Used multer's diskStorage function to define the file system location where I want the uploaded files to get stored.

**And exposed 3 endpoints -**
 
1st for accepting single file upload, **keyname - singleFile**
 
2nd for accepting an array of files for a key name, **keyname - multipleFiles**
3rd for accepting an array of single/array files for different key names.

**I am referring the following-**
1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer
2. https://medium.com/@bmshamsnahid/nodejs-file-upload-using-multer-3a904516f6d2

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var multer  = require('multer')
var async = require('async')

var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.listen(4300, function () {
    console.log('listening on port 4300!');
});


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, '/home/user/Desktop/node/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
});
var upload = multer({storage: storage});

app.post('/single', upload.single('singleFile'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file.filename);
    res.send({'message': 'File received! k thnkx bye!'});
});

app.post('/multiple', upload.array('multipleFiles', 3), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.files);

    async.each(req.files, function (temp, callback) {
       console.log(temp);
    }, function (err) {
       if (err) {
           console.log('Error ' + err);
       } else {
        console.log('Success');
       }
    });

    res.send({'message': 'Files received! k thnkx bye!'});
});

var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'singleFile', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'multipleFiles', maxCount: 3 }])
app.post('/fields', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    res.send({'message': 'Files received! k thnkx bye!'});
});
```

**Following is the API call made using Postman tool -**
**1. Single file upload API-** 
[image]

**2. Multiple files upload API-**
[image]

**I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined" on the console.logs for some mistake probably.**

**Debug Console-**

```
/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.11.0/bin/node --inspect-brk=10250 Node-Tutorials/Apps/multer.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:10250/87170633-e582-4ac5-b099-0d2e6d090a7f
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
listening on port 4300!
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
    at /home/user/office/node-crud-app/Node-Tutorials/Apps/multer.js:23:26
    at callbacks (/home/user/office/node-crud-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at multerMiddleware (/home/user/office/node-crud-app/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:18:41)
    at callbacks (/home/user/office/node-crud-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/home/user/office/node-crud-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at pass (/home/user/office/node-crud-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/home/user/office/node-crud-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router [as handle] (/home/user/office/node-crud-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/home/user/office/node-crud-app/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at cors (/home/user/office/node-crud-app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
```

**Can someone please help fix my code, to download the files on the file system?**

Comment: Can you please post us the HTML of the upload page?

Comment: @Sridhar updated the question, added screenshot of API requests

Comment: Your code works fine in my laptop. I reproduced the error you reported by making a POST call without attaching any file. Can you check is this the case?

Comment: Can you share the request screenshot?
I get an "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
" on the localhost:4300/single API and "undefined" on the localhost:4300/multiple API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined" on the console.logs for some mistake probably.

This could be possible if the `file` is empty.

[image: error message when not uploading a file]

Handling the case,

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var multer = require('multer')
var async = require('async')

var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.listen(4300, function () {
  console.log('listening on port 4300!');
});


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, './uploads')
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
});
var upload = multer({storage: storage});

const params = {
  '/single': 'file',
  '/multiple': 'files'
};

function validate(req, res, next) {
  let param = params[req.url];
  if (!req[param]) {
    return res.send({
      errors: {
        message: `${param} cant be empty`
      }
    });
  }
  next();
}

app.post('/single', upload.single('singleFile'), validate, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.file.filename);
  res.send({'message': 'File received! k thnkx bye!'});
});

app.post('/multiple', upload.array('multipleFiles', 3), validate, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.files);

  async.each(req.files, function (temp, callback) {
    console.log(temp);
  }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error ' + err);
    } else {
      console.log('Success');
    }
  });

  res.send({'message': 'Files received! k thnkx bye!'});
});

var cpUpload = upload.fields([{name: 'singleFile', maxCount: 1}, {name: 'multipleFiles', maxCount: 3}])
app.post('/fields', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req);
  res.send({'message': 'Files received! k thnkx bye!'});
});
```

Should handle the empty file upload.

Comment: added your validate function and parameter in the API code, gives me "File cant be empty" in both cases :/

Comment: ah worked, for /multiple and /fields I do the same? added validate function as param?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje updated the code to handle multiple file as well :)

Answer (score 0):

try consoling req.files.filename.

I found filename in req.files.filename.

Correction -  req.files is array of object.

Comment: hmmm I think if it's `req.files`, it should be an array shouldn't it? I mean `req.files = [ {...}]`

Comment: @Manish same code? I get the same error on the /single API and undefined on /multiple API

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje use async.each on req.files and console inside async.

Comment: still getting "undefined" in console log, I've updated the code with async.